# raster2pgsql size problem

Tags: postgis, gdal, postgresql, raster2pgsql

I am about to import a raster (*.tif with 50mb, size 3301x21676, pixel size 10x10*) into postgres with raster2pgsql.

With small extracts of the image it works but ...

raster2pgsql [myfilename].tif -F [somename] > [somename].sql

My problem is that I end up with a huge sql file (about 1 GB) for the 50mb TIFF. 
with `psql \i  somename.sql`
this ends up with an rollback and `can't change 0 to 100000 byte` error

I already tried to make tiles with raster2pgsql, but it doesnt change anything for the sql file.

Any advice?

Comment: i found an solution. it was an encoding problem, i solvesd it with chcp 1252.

Answer (score 1):

i found an solution. it was an encoding problem, i solvesd it with chcp 1252.

http://postgis.net/docs/RT_FAQ.html#qa_raster_fails_encoding_conversion